# I Unable to move images in S3 bucket from our main server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload my images in the amazon s3 bucket. My images database uploaded to another web server. I am unable to move it to the S3 bucket. I referred to some solutions from StackOverflow.

**Here is my code I have tried:**

```
use \usr\share\php\AWSSDKforPHP\S3;
use \usr\share\php\AWSSDKforPHP\S3\S3Client;
use \usr\share\php\AWSSDKforPHP\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'cdn.example.com';

$keyname = $newfilename;
                        
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
    'key'    => "**********************",
    'secret' => "**********************************"
    ]
]);

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile' => $oldfilepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ]);

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . PHP_EOL;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Showing error in output:**

> Fatal error: Class 'usr\share\php\AWSSDKforPHP\S3\S3Client' not found in /var/www/html/cron-jobs/shift-img.php on line 35

Comment: "S3Client" not installed or not configured properly.

Comment: How you can justify that? 

We have already checked it's installed properly. S3Client file is already in the folder I have checked manually.

Comment: Does it need `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`? There is some sample code at: [PutObject.php - AWS Code Sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-s3-PutObject.php.html)

Comment: Your S3Client is not found that why I told you Not install OR Configure properly.